# How to check result from boost::fusion:at_key?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

Example from boost tutorial:

```
using namespace fields;
std::string person_name = at_key<name>(a_person);
int person_age = at_key<age>(a_person);
```

How to check wheather there is no such key in this map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a given sequence contains an element associated with a given `Key`, one can (and should) use `has_key<Key> (seq)`, as in the below example.

```
if (has_key<fields::age> (some_seq)) {
  int person_age = at_key<fields::age> (some_seq);
}
```

---

#### Documentation:

- [**boost.org** - **`has_key`** - 1.55.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/functions/has_key.html)